# 'Long stories are easy to tell to the children' and 'The children are easy to tell long stories to' - entailment?

Tags: syntax, semantics

What is the entailment pattern across the next two sentences: *Long stories are easy to tell to the children and The children are easy to tell long stories to?*

I am studying entailment patterns and I have come across a curious pair of sentences:

(1) Long stories are easy to tell to the children.
(2) The children are easy to tell long stories to.

I think these two sentences are truth-conditionally equivalent. In other words, it seems that if the one sentence is true, then the other is necessarily also true. That is my intuition, anyway. Since I am not sure about my assessment, it would be good if someone here could provide some commentary about such cases. Note that this pair of sentences is similar to the following pair:

(3) This sonata is easy to play on that violin.
(4) That violin is easy to play this sonata on.

This pair was, I believe, discussed by Chomsky at some point. My intuition is that these two sentences are also truth-conditionally equivalent, although I am again not sure. Note that both pairs of sentences involve the adjective easy, which is of the sort that allows so-called *tough-movement*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Tl:dr**

Yes, the two sentences convey exactly the same information, packaged in slightly different ways. This is similar to how the three sentences below semantically entail each other:

- Someone sent Bob a book
- Bob was sent a book.
- A book was sent to Bob..

---

**Full answer**

It might be easier to see how these sentences relate to each other by investigating some other closely related sentences. The sentence below is grammatical but clunky:

> 1. [To tell long stories to the children] is easy.

The reason is that we find such sentences clunky seems to be that it is more difficult for us to process sentences which have clauses as subjects. One solution to this problem that the language makes available to us is the extraposition construction. In this construction we stick a meaningless dummy pronoun *it* in the subject position and shunt the non-finite clause down to the end of the matrix clause where it is easier to process.:

> 2. **It** is easy [to tell long stories to the  children].

Examples (1) and (2) mean exactly the same thing. [Notice that in (2), the subject pronoun is not a referential  pronoun. It doesn't *refer* to the non-finite clause. It is just a meaningless filler for the obligatory subject position.]

We can compare example (2) here with the first of the Original Poster's examples, which uses a *tough*-movement construction:

> 3. **Long stories** are easy [to tell ___ to the children].

This time, the non-finite clause still appears at the end of the matrix clause, where it would now be analysed as the complement of *easy*. However, instead of plugging the obligatory subject position with a dummy pronoun, we 'extract' one of the noun phrases (NPs) from the non-finite clause and use this NP to plug the subject position. This leaves a gap in the non-finite clause which is semantically co-indexed with the subject. We could informally represent the example in either of the following ways:

> - **Long stories** are easy [to tell <s>long stories</s> to the children].
> - **Long stories**<sub>i</sub> are easy [to tell ___<sub>i</sub> to the children].

The example above means exactly the same as example (2). They reconstruct semantically in the same way. Meaning-wise, the subject *long stories* in (3) belongs together with the rest of the non-finite clause.

In that particular example, it happens to be the direct object of the verb *tell* which was 'extracted'. However, we can alternatively extract indirect objects or the objects of prepositions. The latter is what happens in the original Poster's second example:

> 4. The children are easy to tell stories to:

We could represent this informally using either of the following:

> - **The children** are easy [to tell long stories to <s>the children</s>]
> - **The children**<sub>i</sub> are easy [to tell long stories to ___<sub>i</sub>].

Each of the examples above signifies that whatever quality is indicated by the predicate *easy* is applicable to whatever is represented by the non-finite clause *[for an underspecified teller] to tell long stories to the children*. There is no chance, therefore, of their different variants having different meanings. (1)–(4) entail each other.

---

<sup>An over-my-shoulder commentator has said that the easiness involved must surely apply to the denotee of the subject NP. For example, suppose the  subject NP is *Margery* and that Margery is both easy-going, inspiring, and makes it rewarding to do difficult and unpleasant things for but that the action described by the infinitival VP is fiendishly difficult , unpleasant and not at all easy to achieve, then the following would be the sentence opted for:</sup>

<sup>5. Margery is easy to do extraordinarily difficult and unpleasant things for.</sup>

<sup>However, the sentence above means exactly the same as:</sup>

<sup>6. Extraordinarily difficult and unpleasant things are easy to do for Margery.</sup>

<sup>And this means the same as:</sup>

<sup>- It is easy to do extraordinarily difficult and unpleasant things for Margery.</sup>

Comment: You managed not to mention [_Tough_-movement](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/143566/15299), though you did get co-indexing in there.

Comment: @jlawler I did, I believe, though only fleetingly ;) "*2, which uses a tough-movement construction:*"

Comment: What do you mean by "functions semantically as the subject of the sentence"? Subjecthood is usually defined as a syntactic, not semantic, property.

Comment: @TKR This is a placeholder comment whilst I feed the sprogs. Yes, I agree (that there is no semantic role that should be associated with subjects). But one has to be able to interpret the subject to be able to understand the clause. In the extraposition in (2), for example, *it* is uninterpretable. The construction can be thought of as conveying "stick that clause at the end in this *it*-space here". I'm not suggesting that there is a semantic role that should be associated with subjects.

Comment: Thanks. But (3) and (4) have interpretable NPs in the subject position, so it seems the logic of the last paragraph only holds up if you assume a deep structure where they aren't subjects.

Comment: And in fact that's what a derivational solution would do. Rather than insert epicycles, just demonstrate the relation.

Comment: @TKR [Or the construction tells you to construct the subject by reconstructing the gapped non-finite clause around a place-holder NP, but I won't try to defend that here]. Point taken. Will cogitate - unless you have a suggestion for an edit?

Comment: Not specifically, no... Intuitively I agree that the sentences seem truth-conditionally equivalent,I'm just not sure that this can be convincingly proven syntactically.

Comment: @TKR How is that edit?

Comment: That does seem to me like a better way of putting it in a theory-independent way (especially in combination with the footnote).

Comment: @TKR Thank you for the helpful and challenging feedback.

Comment: I agree with the consensus here, namely that the two sentences in each pair in the question are truth-conditionally equivalent. They shouldn't be, though -- at least not according to Chomsky (1981) and Pollard & Sag (1994). Both sources argue that the subject of tough-adjectives is thematically charged. Chomsky was hence motivated to put forward his OP analysis of tough-movement.

Comment: @Araucaria - him Thank you for providing such detailed explanation. The different constructions seem pretty clear to me with the examples you put above. Their truth conditions do seem to be the same as you have demonstrated.

Comment: @TimOsborne I take it that that means that it's assigned the role by the predicate adjective?

Comment: @TimOsborne Do they actually use the phrase "thematically charged"? The metaphor is coherent with "polarity" and "binding", and a nice fit for the invited inferences of _Tough_-moved subjects.

Comment: @Araucaria - him. Yes, that is what it means. Here are a couple of lines that Chomsky (1981: 309) wrote about the sentence _John is easy to please_: "There is good evidence that the matrix subject _John_ is lexically-inserted into its S-structure position. The matrix subject position must, therefore, be a theta-position, ...

Comment: @jlawler. Not exactly in those words, but see my comment just above, and concerning the other source (Pollard & Sag 1994: 167), they examine sentences such as _Kim would be easy to bribe_. They write in this regard: "There is considerable evidence in favor of our claim that the subject of _easy_ is role-assigned." They then proceed to produce some less than convincing observations in support of their stance.

Comment: I would consider it pragmatic (invited inference) instead of syntactic (I dunno if roles are currently syntactic; the theories shift a lot). Though this is right on the borderline, a natural target for irony and double entendre.

Comment: @jlawler. Do you mean that entailment does not obtain between the two sentences in the question? Or do you mean that entailment does obtain, but that there is an additional inference that is pragmatic and that explains why one would choose the one sentence over the other?

Comment: By me, entailment is pragmatic. So is presupposition and the other relations between sentences.

Comment: @jlawler. That does not help. :-(

Answer (score 2):

Any entailment would depend on context, and it is not hard to find situations where one is true and the other isn't. For instance:

*Long stories are easy to tell to the children, because I just need to prepare a few puppets, and can adlib most of the dialogue. So I can keep them occupied for 30 minutes with hardly any preparation.
However the children are NOT easy to tell long stories to, because their cursed parents fill them with sugar before dropping them off, and all they want to do is run around screaming.*

**UPDATE:** I think I need to be clearer on what I'm saying. Given X ("Long stories are easy to tell to the children"), Y ("The children are easy to tell long stories to") is either true or false. The information to decide that is not contained within X and Y. X therefore does not entail Y.

Or, alternatively (to show that Y does not entail X, either):

*The children are easy to tell long stories to, because they are an intelligent, curious bunch. However long stories are NOT easy to tell to the children - they are not suited to just reading out loud the way the classic short stories are, so I need to go through and prepare notes for myself in advance.*

Comment: Thank you for giving this insight! This leads me to think more of the existence of context. Maybe it is something related to Pragmatics. I myself am not sure though.

Comment: @Buffoon , Darren, That looks good but it won't go through. Consider: "*The children are easy to tell long stories to, because I just need to prepare a few puppets, and can adlib most of the dialogue. So I can keep them occupied for 30 minutes with hardly any preparation. However, long stories are NOT easy to tell to the children, because their cursed parents fill them with sugar before dropping them off, and all they want to do is run around screaming*" We can change the children and stories around as much as we want, it makes no difference.

Comment: Also notice that quite generally we can even say "It's easy to X because of A, but it's not easy to X because of B" (and also that this does not necessarily make "It's easy to X because of A" false--although it does make it's interpretation subject to pragmatics, of course).

Comment: @Araucaria-him The question was if X entails Y. My examples were to show that the information in sentence X and in sentence Y is not enough to say that, and to show how different context means X can be true and Y can be not true. And a second example to show how Y can be true and X can be not true.

Comment: @DarrenCook Yes, but as shown by reversing the X and Y sentences within your contexts there is nothing that makes X true and Y false there. And the fact that we can say "It's easy to X because of A. But it's not easy to X because of B" shows that that kind of test wouldn’t work anyway, I don’t think.

Comment: Interesting answer and exchange here! The counterargument provided by Araucaria is convincing.

Comment: @TimOsborne: I remained unconvinced :-)  (Started writing more here, but added it as an update to my answer instead.)

Comment: The point you are making again does not go through. Consider a simpler example: _I like tuna casserole because it tastes good, but at the same time, I do not like tuna casserole because of the cholesterol._ I think your sentences are doing the same thing.

Comment: BTW, two comments have now used the phrase "does not go through". What does that mean?

Comment: There are a number of testable relations besides entailment; there's presupposition, of course, and conversational implicature, and invited inference, and semi-entailment. Plus all the negative mutations. Entailment is useful but not  subtle.

Comment: @jlawler. I am not familiar with "invited inference" and "semi-entailment". Would you please elaborate on those notions and/or provide a link. Thanks.

Comment: [Geis and Zwicky 1971](https://web.stanford.edu/~zwicky/on-invited-inferences.pdf) introduced the term "invited inference". Semi-entailment has the following definition:  A semi-entails B iff  for all speakers who believe A, those speakers believe B, and B is synthetic. I.e, B is not logically true, but is possibly false. See [this survey](https://d.lib.msu.edu/etd/15872/datastream/OBJ/view) for details.

Comment: When your post uses sentence X and then uses sentence A as evidence that it is true, it could just as easily have used sentence Y and sentence A as evidence to show it is true. The post assumes that it's some property of the  subject NP that makes the sentence true or false. Swap sentences X and Y and see if you think that still holds. For me it doesn't. Consider ***Long stories are easy to tell to the children, because they are a curious intelligent bunch***, a cut-and-shut from the last set of examples, which according to that reasoning should be false and a non-sequitur given the evidence.

Comment: @jlawler. Thank you for the interesting sources. I am reading them with much interest.